# Google Data Studio: Average Number of Sessions based on selected country values

Tags: calculated-field, looker-studio

Let's say that for the dimension `country` I have 4 values and for each of the 4 I have the respective number of `Sessions`. E.g.

```
+---------+----------+
| country | Sessions |
+---------+----------+
| Italy   | 10       |
| France  | 12       |
| Germany | 14       |
| Spain   | 16       |
+---------+----------+
```

I want to compute and output in a scorecard the average number of `Sessions`, only for those specific countries. So, in the example, the output should be 13.

I tried with the following calculated field but it doesn't work:

```
Sessions * AVG(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(country, '^Italy|France|Germany|Spain.*') THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter based on the country dimension using the Matching RegEx operator.
Then apply this to a scorecard with the metric sessions. In the Data tab on the right hand side, you should be able to click on a little pencil icon for the metric, and choose the aggregation method as average instead of sum.
You may not have this option if you're using the GA connector. In this case, there should be an Average Session metric in the data source.

Answer (score 0):

One way it can be achieved is by using a Filter Control and a Calculated Field:

## 1) [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144)

Add the component with the *Dimension* set to `Country` and then add a *Default Selection* (a comma separated list of the required countries):

```
Italy, France, Germany, Spain
```

### 2) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) ([Scorecard](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479))

```
Sessions / COUNT_DISTINCT(Country)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d415c7cd-907a-49c7-9b05-12522560f2f6) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]